# Golden Brown Flying beetle identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Bug (probably a beetle) flew into my house tonight with golden body and black stripes. I live in pacific asia. 
[image]
[image]

.

Comment: Pacific Asia could be a bit vague as a location. As well if you can specify the season (you just saw it now or few month ago) and what kind of habitat your living (urban area, jungle, desert and so on).